# sorting a GO struct by date which is defined via proto message

Tags: go, proto

I have defined a message in proto file:

```
my.proto
--------
message Holiday {
  string title = 1;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp date = 2;
}
```

After compiling, it creates my.pb.go

Now in my go code, I have an slice of Holiday.

```
main.go
-------
holidays := []my.Holiday{...}
```

I have to sort this slice by Holiday.date. As per the doc if I want to sort using sort.Sort then I have to implement Len, Swap & Less method. But I cannot define these receiver method in my go code because `Holiday` is coming from the different package (my.pb.go).
Is there any way to sort this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use [`sort.Slice`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice), which doesn't require implementing `sort.Interface`.

> Slice sorts the slice x given the provided less function. It panics if x is not a slice.

```golang
sort.Slice(holidays, func(i, j int) bool {
    return holidays[i].GetDate().Before(holidays[j].GetDate())  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SortKeys` example [in the sort.Sort documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort) shows how to accomplish this by using an ad-hoc struct:

```
// A Planet defines the properties of a solar system object.
type Planet struct {
    name     string
    mass     earthMass
    distance au
}

// By is the type of a "less" function that defines the ordering of its Planet arguments.
type By func(p1, p2 *Planet) bool

// Sort is a method on the function type, By, that sorts the argument slice according to the function.
func (by By) Sort(planets []Planet) {
    ps := &planetSorter{
        planets: planets,
        by:      by, // The Sort method's receiver is the function (closure) that defines the sort order.
    }
    sort.Sort(ps)
}

// planetSorter joins a By function and a slice of Planets to be sorted.
type planetSorter struct {
    planets []Planet
    by      func(p1, p2 *Planet) bool // Closure used in the Less method.
}

// Len is part of sort.Interface.
func (s *planetSorter) Len() int {
    return len(s.planets)
}

// Swap is part of sort.Interface.
func (s *planetSorter) Swap(i, j int) {
    s.planets[i], s.planets[j] = s.planets[j], s.planets[i]
}

// Less is part of sort.Interface. It is implemented by calling the "by" closure in the sorter.
func (s *planetSorter) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return s.by(&s.planets[i], &s.planets[j])
}
```

Given that `sort.Sort` only takes a `sort.Interface`, it doesn't care about what data structure you are using or what type you are actually swapping.

Answer (score 1):

The [sort package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/sort) shows two examples that answer the question.

The [first package example](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#example-package) declares a slice type with the required methods:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

type ByAge []Person

func (a ByAge) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a ByAge) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a ByAge) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i].Age < a[j].Age }

...
sort.Sort(ByAge(people))
```

Notice that the Len, Swap and Less methods are on the slice type defined for sorting, not on the struct type. You can define that type in your own package.

The [sort.Slice example](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#example-Slice) shows how to sort with a less function only:

```
sort.Slice(people, func(i, j int) bool { return people[i].Name < people[j].Name })
```

In this example, there's no need to define types for the purpose of soring.